# How to distribute the detail of a record according to your pentil

Tags: powerbi

I am currently finding a pentil in a measure, which varies according to the week and the region. As I am expressing it in a graph, I need this pentile to be stored in a column; which I am doing by crossing tables

[image]

the 'cuartil' column only has the values of pentile (1P, 2P, 3P, 4P, 5P), and the connection of the two tables is made as follows:

```
 suma_inci_total = CALCULATE (
  SUM( inci_total[nro_incidencias] );
  FILTER ( inci_total; [pentil_radar] IN VALUES ('axis'[cuartil]) )
 )
```

and the graph can be seen as normal as shown in the photo,but the problem is when I want to deepen the graph

[image]

The distribution of the 'site' column is not carried out in each pentil that corresponds to it, but everything accumulates in the first pentil.

[image]
photo of the first pentil

[image]
photo of the second pentil

[image]

How would you make this distribution possible?

Comment: If you want to go a level deeper, you need to press the arrow which starts as one and ends as two (two buttons right)

Comment: what I want is that when I click on each bar of the graph, it will take me to the sites that belong to that bar

Comment: Can you add an image of the table model/relation of the 2 tables you are using.

Comment: I already added it, but as you can see there is no relationship between the tables because what I get in the table 'table_ranking' is a measure called 'quartile', but I want to show it as an axis of the graph, so one with the 'axis' table, as seen in the formula that you add in this publication

Comment: I do not see the table inci_total in your model? Seems to me relevant because your measure is based on it..

Comment: Excuse me, I was wrong about the table, I already edited it

Comment: Please give me some raw data so I understand better what you are working with (I believe I can help you).

Comment: I have a universe of data, which is filtered by universe and by region, so what I want is to divide it into 5 parts, that's what I'm calling them 'pentiles', but these 'pentiles' I find them in measure (so they can vary with The filters). but since I want to put these pentiles as an axis in a graph, that is why I am joining with the 'quartile' column of the axis table

Comment: but I want the sites to be distributed according to the 'pentil' that corresponds to it ... since for now they only accumulate in the first

Comment: If you mak little raw test data this will help.

Comment: I made a better detailed post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540996/how-to-distribute-the-subcategory-of-an-axis-in-power-bi