# how to distribute the subcategory of an axis in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

At the beginning I had this table

[image]

what I want is to divide the universe into 3 sections, so I do the following

i believe in column

```
UniqueRank = 
RANKX (
 inci;
  FORMAT (inci[nro_casos]; "0000" ) & inci[region] & inci[site]
)
```

then I create two measures

```
 ranking_total = 
 RANKX (
   ALLSELECTED ( inci );
   inci[UniqueRank];
   MAX ( inci[UniqueRank] )
 )

 tirdh_case = IF(inci[ranking_total]<=COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(inci))*0.33;"3P";
 IF(inci[ranking_total]<=COUNTROWS(ALLSELECTED(inci))*0.66;"2P";"1P"))
```

[image]

Then I would stay as follows. As you can see, filters of week and region can be applied and normal is divided into three parts, but I want to show it in a graph, and I want to put the tirdh_case as the axis, for this I create a new table called 'axis'

[image]

so I create the measure that intersects these two tables

```
suma_inci = CALCULATE (
  SUM( inci[nro_casos] );
  FILTER ( inci; [tirdh_case] IN VALUES ('axis'[indice]) )
)
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, the graph works perfectly, but I am inserting the 'site' column as a subcategory, so that when I click on each bar it shows me the sites that belong to that bar, but what happens is that all the sites are accumulate in the first bar ... how would you link the sites and categorize correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This is logical because Measures are dynamically calculated based on your selection. So when you select your bar with the "P1", it needs to recalculate your splitting what is not possible because it is what you select. So if you want to go this level deeper, you need to make your measures a column so it is static divided.

Your column is than like:

```
tirdh_case = 
var maxRank = MAX(inci[UniqueRank])
var splitNr = 3
var divider = maxRank/3
return CEILING((1 + maxRank - inci[UniqueRank])/divider;1) & "P"
```

You do not need an extra table now because you can use this column as your axis. I made it such that you can change the splitNr to your liking.

End result: [image]

Comment: but what happens if I apply the region and week filters, you should also calculate a new 1P, 2P, 3P. That's why I did it with measure, but how would I add that filter to your new column

Comment: What happens is that if I apply a filter to your code that you have made, the partitions would not be equal or approximate